# Is it not possible to skew things in illustrator as in photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When transforming in photoshop if you alt+shift then drag a corner you can skew both corners. The other corners being at side that is opposite in terms of horizontal and vertical depending on the direction that corner is being adjusted. And other corner moves inversely. 
This helps in making perspective. I can't do this in Illustrator. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `Free Transform Tool`:

1. Select `Free Transform Tool` or press `E`.
2. Click and hold one of the corners of the object's bounding box and *then* press and hold `Ctrl` / `Cmd` (it is important to press `Ctrl` *after* clicking a corner). You will see that now you can drag this corner.
3. Now, without releasing both `Ctrl` and the mouse button, press and hold `Alt+Shift` and the tool will work just as you want in your question.

Comment: why is it this complicated...

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why. Having a separate tool named Free Transform Tool I would myself expect it to work in a less complicated manner...

Comment: i am learning illustrator, coming from photoshop, i stumble on things again and again that could be simpler and robust. Like choosing color.

Comment: Command/Ctrl makes the Free Transform Tool operate like the **Sheer tool**.. so..... Yes this works, but if the modifier keys are too much, just use the Sheer Tool.

Answer (score 2):

Free Transform works. There's also a Shear Tool:

[image: shear tool]

As well as Object > Transform > Shear or right-click/control-click and choose Transform > Shear from the contextual menu.

Comment: yea but it is different it moves both points

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to skew, not shear.

Comment: Don't get hung up on Adobe's mis-use of different terms to do the same thing. Shear in Illustrator is the same as Skew in Photoshop. They operate a bit differently, but both accomplish the same thing.